# Issue installing plugins when using both PhoneGap Build and local browser

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

We're using PhoneGap Build to build our app for iOS and Android. During development, however, it's convenient to test in the local browser. This seemed straightforward to me, but I can't figure out an easy way to get the plugins to install on my local machine.

My config file is here: https://gist.github.com/matthewgertner/7ed0fb5f9c6882c7f197. I'm using `<gap:plugin>` to tell PhoneGap Build which plugins to use. But when I create a local app and run `cordova prepare browser`, it only downloads the plugins if I use `<plugin>` rather than `<gap:plugin>`.

Am I missing something or do I have to list all the plugins twice (with both `<plugin>` and `<gap:plugin>`) in order to use the same `config.xml` both locally and with PhoneGap Build?

Answer (score 0):

For local testing you could just install the plugins via the CLI. (More info [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html)).

For example the following works for me:

```
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
cordova run android
```

This will let you automatically download, install, and run plugins on your local machine or mobile device without the need for building on the Adobe cloud.

Don't worry this won't interfere with your Phonegap configuration. I use this method for local building Android and the Phonegap configs for remote building for iOS.

Comment: I've been doing that until now but I want to make the process as automatic as possible. Isn't it possible to use the same `config.xml` to install the plugins both locally and on PhoneGap Build?

Comment: Ah automating it further may be possible with the new features in cordova 5. [This](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/04/21/tools-release.html) shows that `cordova prepare` can indeed do what you are suggesting. Have you checked that you are using the latest version of cordova ? . P.S. In the link it specifies that `plugin` must be used. So right now it looks like both `gap:plugin` and `plugin` are required.

Comment: I'll wait to see if anyone else chimes in but that does appear to be the case for now. In the meantime I'm using `sed -e 's/gap:plugin/plugin/g' < ../config.xml > config.xml`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

@Matthew,
the `browser` option is not well understood - yet! Even so, I have seen one article on it, and that came from a pointer in the official blog post.

My continuing notes are at
[Cordova Browser Platform](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/browser-platform.md).

I will summarize.

> In theory you can develop on your browser with this, and fine tune on your mobile device.
>
> **Browser as a platform for your PhoneGap/Cordova apps - September 24, 2014**
> http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/9/24/Browser-as-a-platform-for-your-PhoneGapCordova-apps
>
> Working with a limited number of plugins
>
> - Camera
> - Device
> - Device Motion (Accelerometer)
> - Device Orientation (Compass)
> - Network Information